# Alternative of creating snapshot of uiview from renderInContext

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiview, snapshot

I am a newbie in ios and want to create a snapshot of a uiview and i am taking snapshots at 30 frames per second and i am using renderInContext method to take screenshots.
But it takes much time and for that i have to reduce my frame rate.
So is there any alternative for it??
Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be the alternative to take snapshot of UIView
[UIGetScreenImage](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html). This was private API before, crowd says apple has open up, please confirm before using it :)

Comment: I believe yet it is private because when you search that function in developer.apple.com there is no result coming up. So....

Comment: Also you can't upload the app using a private api because apple will reject the apps using private api.

Comment: @AniShroff @Mathew I already warned him to check, you can also refer to this link, `if it is true`.

Comment: thanks guys,i will see to it and one more thing ,using opengl and taking eaglview snapshots is better or not?

Comment: i just want that same time will be taken to create the snapshot of a view regardless the number of subviews it has because renderInContext take in consideration every subview so if a view has many subviews rendering takes time.
I want fixed time for every snapshot so as to maintain the frasmerate of 30fps.
So in this case should i use opengl??

Plz guyss help needed here